# How to pass pointer to a member within class to outer class?

Tags: c++, class, pointer-to-member, member-pointers

I am trying to pass a pointer to memeber of class(Dialog::handler) from its method(in scope of Dialog::render) to some outer method(Button::OnClick).

Here is a small example:

```cpp
        class Button
        {
        public:
            void OnClick(void (*handler)())
            {
                handler();
            }
        };

        class Dialog
        {
        public:
            void handler()
            {
                //do stuff
            }
            void render()
            {
                auto button = new Button;
                //Source of problem
                button->OnClick(this->*handler);
            }
        };
```

But compiler shows error:

> non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Also I triend other combinations, like:

- this->handler.
- &this.handler.
- this.*handler.
- etc

But obviously they failed.

Comment: Is there a part of the code that cannot be modified? I am asking because once you fixed this error you will run into the next: `void (*)()` is a pointer to a free function, but not to a member function

Comment: ...also I would expect that the `Button` stores the callback somehow and calls it in `onClick`. Having to pass the callback each time `onClick` is called looks a bit backwards

Comment: I think, the way you are doing it, you can only pass free functions to `OnClick`. You could change it to `OnClick(void (Dialog::*handler)())`. However this way you can only pass member functions of `Dialog` to `OnClick`, not of classes deriving from `Dialog`.  And you always need a pointer to a `Dialog` to call the handler.

Maybe you wan't to overthink the whole idea.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 this is just pure example which I am playing with to study Patterns. Here you can find a pseudocode  https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method and here is also my problem at this pseudocode `okButton.onClick(closeDialog)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `std::function` and pass it a lambda in which you've caught `this` of the object you'd like to call back:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Button {
public:
    void OnClick(std::function<void()> handler) {
        handler();
    }
};

class Dialog {
public:
    void handler() {
        std::cout << "Dialog::handler\n";
    }
    void render() {
        auto button = new Button;
        // a lambda catching "this" Dialog.
        button->OnClick([this] { this->handler(); });
        delete button;                               // you didn't delete your button
    }
};

int main() {
    Dialog d;
    d.render();
}
```

---

But it looks like you should probably inherit from a common base class that has a `virtual void handler()` so you can pass object pointers/references around instead. A rough idea:

```
#include <iostream>

class VisualBase {
public:
    virtual void handler() = 0;
    virtual ~VisualBase() = 0;
};

VisualBase::~VisualBase() {}

class Button : public VisualBase {
public:
    void handler() override {}

    void OnClick(VisualBase* caller) {
        caller->handler(); 
    }
};

class Dialog : public VisualBase {
public:
    void handler() override { 
        std::cout << "Dialog::handler\n"; 
    }

    void render() {
        Button button;
        button.OnClick(this);
    }
};

int main() {
    Dialog d;
    d.render();
}
```

Comment: First one solution with STL is preferable for me, even I was looking for pure C++ solution. Its strange why ".*" and "->*" operands didn't help.

Comment: @OlegKmechak `*` is for dereferencing pointers. If you want to get a pointer to an existing thing, you need `&`.

Comment: @churill mentioned the problem with your current signature. It would have to be `OnClick(void (Dialog::*handler)())` to be able to receive the `Dialog` member function pointer as argument, and that would make it hard to use in the general case.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh probably I understood! Class should be specified in this statement `(Dialog::*handler)())` cos member functions instead of free functions can use other members of class, thats why we have to specify to compiller also a class name __`Dialog`__.